# Send Graph QL Query as message through a socket connection in c# .net Core

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-core, graphql

I am trying to send a Graph QL query as a message through a socket connection , but it seems there's something wrong with the query I send , as I get this message

`{"errorCode":417,"id":-1,"payload":"Missing required numerical field 'id' "}`

here's the query I send :

```
              var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "id","1"},
                    { "query", "subscription {message { node {id content channel { id } from { __typename  display_name }} }}" },
                    { "type" ,  "'request'" }
                };


                await client.SendInstant(JsonConvert.SerializeObject( values));
```

any help to figure out what's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `{ "id","1"},` to `{ "id",1},`. When you serialize the object it converts string into a string, yet the webservice which you are sending the data to expects a number there.